# How can I get one column of a Numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am triyng to get the 3 columns of a NumPy (RGB) array:

```
print px
[[[  0   0   0]
  [255 255 255]
  [255   0   0]
  [  0 255   0]
  [  0   0 255]]]

print px[:,0]
print px[:,1]
print px[:,2]

[[0 0 0]]
[[255 255 255]]
[[255   0   0]]
```

but I would like to get the R, G and B like

```
[[0 255 255 0 0]]
[[0 255 0 255 0]]
[[0 255 0 0 255]]
```

Could you help me?

Thank you

Hugo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your array `px` is three-dimensional: the first dimension has just a single element: the complete arrays containing rows and colums. The second dimension is rows, the third is colums. Therefore, to select a column, and have it embedded in the outermost dimension like you have, use the following:

```
>>> print px[:,:,0]
[[  0 255 255   0   0]]

>>> print px[:,:,1]
[[  0 255   0 255   0]]

>>> print px[:,:,2]
[[  0 255   0   0 255]]
```

Comment: I would like to transform this array into a Pandas Dataframe to use a scatter matrix. Should I use?
f = pd.DataFrame(px[:,:,:], columns=['R', 'G', 'B'])